# Google Sheets replace spaces with -, remove parentheses and periods

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, excel-formula, substitution

I am attempting to generate a string to use in a URL from some data in a Google Sheet.

Here is a number or rows

```
Logan
Louisville
North Seattle (Lynnwood)
Mesa
Minneapolis
Nashville
National City
St. Paul (Oakdale)
Oklahoma City
```

I need to replace spaces with a -, then remove any periods or parentheses.
This is where I am at now, which works for spaces but not sure where to go for periods and parentheses

`substitute(lower(A1)," ","-")`

Would, inside lower(), I use `REGEXREPLACE` to look for periods and parentheses?

looking for an output of

```
logan
louisville
north-seattle-lynnwood
mesa
minneapolis
nashville
national-city
st-paul-pakdale
oklahoma-city
```

Thanks

Comment: st-Paul-Oakdale ?

Comment: @player0 typo, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, "[\(\).]", ), " ", "-")))
```

[image]